# Programmatically detect Heroku dyno size at run time?

Tags: heroku

Say I have a Heroku app that is deployed to various different sizes of dynos over time or by different users. How can I reliably determine what size dyno the app is running in? I know that `$DYNO` will tell me what the process name is (e.g. `web.123` or `worker.456`), but none of the Heroku environment vars indicate whether that's a 256MB 1X, 1024MB 2X, or a 6GB PX dyno.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heroku support provided this answer, which they refused to document because it's a hack, and they intend to provide a reasonable solution in the future.

> The only way to do this would be to shell out and call `ulimit -u` to get the max number of tasks. 256 for 1X dynos, 512 for 2X and MAX_SUPPORTED_BY_LINUX for PX.

Bash example:

```
function dyno_size() {
  case $(ulimit -u) in
    256)
      echo "1X"
      ;;
    512)
      echo "2X"
      ;;
    32768)
      echo "PX"
      ;;
    *)
      echo "unknown"
      ;;
  esac
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's much better than the prior answer, but Heroku's answer is to examine the memory of a dyno using `/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.limit_in_bytes`

https://help.heroku.com/Q386NUGG/how-can-i-determine-the-memory-limit-of-a-dyno

Answer (score 0):

There is a `$DYNO_RAM` variable.

It's correlated with dyno type, and together with `$DYNO` can be enough.

Comment: I got `DYNO_RAM: unbound variable`. $DYNO is set though.