# How to progromatically detect dyno type at runtime?

Tags: heroku

The question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24634958/programmatically-detect-heroku-dyno-size-at-run-time) is very similar. However, the accepted answer there is insufficient and out of date.

I need to know which dyno type is being used at runtime. This is because I need to configure my application according to the resources available, [just as is done automatically with the default java support](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/java-support#adjusting-environment-for-a-dyno-size).

None of the answers in the above linked question provided the specific dyno type used. For example, I need to know if my dyno type is "eco", "standard-2x", etc. Perhaps the accepted answer in the above question attempts to do this, but it has a few issues:

1. It is highly unsteable given that it is based on checking the `ulimit` number, which could change per dyno.
2. It does not include all dynos and rather includes "unknown" for other dyno types.
3. The answer is almost 10 years old, so it is likely invalid.

I also looked into the [Dyno Metadata Lab](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-metadata), but none of the values provided here say the dyno type.